# React Native "this._easing is not a function" with v0.20

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am running into this error on certain pages and not all but can't track it down to anything in my code.

Red Error Modal from simulator:

```
this._easing is not a function. (In 'this._easing((now-this._startTime)/this.duration)', 'this._easing is NaN')


onUpdate
AnimatedImplementation.js @ 216:8

CallTimer

callTimers

__callFunction

<unknown>

guard

CallFunctionreturnFlusedQueue
```

Have upgrading project to v0.20, cleaned xcode's build/run and rn bundles just in case. I'm fairly sure my code isn't using the animation libraries too.

Answer (score 16):

This is an older post, but I found this through Google so hoping this may help some others out there.

For `bounce` and `ease` easings, you don't need to invoke the function if you're not modifying the default params.

```
// this should error
Animated.timing(this.state.animatedValue, {
  toValue: 10,
  duration: 300,
  easing: Easing.bounce()
}).start();
```

If you just pass the reference to `bounce` instead, the error will go away.

```
easing: Easing.bounce
```